Flash drive won't mount after rsync
After using rsync to copy mp3 files to a micro-sd card, the card will not mount on Mac or Android. The rsync command was
rsync -aP source destination
Why would this have messed up the drive?
Disk Utility says the drive has no free space and reports that some cluster chains have too many clusters for its size.

That will depend on what source and destination actually were, respectively ...

What filesystem on the SD card?

The filesystem was exfat

The source was a SMB share and the destination was the sub, sub directory on the sd card. It was mainly copying mp3's.

Rsync is just reading and writing files into a filesystem.  As such, it can't (by itself) mess up hardware or a filesystem.   However if there is already a software bug or a hardware failure present, the stress of rsync writing to the drive can expose this issue.
I think you will need to look elsewhere for what is wrong with your drive.
My first two suspicions are:

Your SD card is counterfeit and does not actually have the advertised capacity.
Your SD card has failed.

If neither of those are true, you may be able to write a new filesystem to the drive and try again.

That makes sense. The timing is just odd because I lost disk access seemingly the instant that rsync kicked off, but otherwise the symptoms match. I'll run SanDisk utilities on it once recovery finishes and submit a warranty claim.
